# How to solve "256966901 Bluetooth: hclo: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f" Message during Boot in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: boot, bluetooth, screen, 19.04

Every time I boot into Ubuntu 19.04 it shows this message. This doesn't cause any problem. The system Boots Up correctly and Bluetooth is also functioning properly. But why this is happening I don't know. And this is annoying..

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue after I upgraded to 20.04. I resolved it by:

1. Changing `AutoEnable=true` to `AutoEnable=false` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.
2. Stopping and disabling `bluetooth.service`:

   ```
   systemctl stop bluetooth.service
   systemctl disable bluetooth.service
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. As a temporary workaround, you can disable Bluetooth from BIOS.